# How can I access blocked sites for free?

Tags: internet

I'm a new Ubuntu user and I live in Iran. I have problems opening many sites, even Google services.

I cannot buy a VPN account..

What can I do to access sites when access is restricted in Ubuntu?

Comment: Close voters: How is this not about Ubuntu? It seems to be very helpful to people using the OS and trying to access blocked sites...

Comment: @searchfgold6789 I'm thinking they are using close votes as a super downvote.

Answer (score 7):

The safest bet is to use the [Tor network](https://www.torproject.org/) to access sites that your ISP has blocked. In Ubuntu, you can download Tor through the Software Center or with the terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

Then, use the `torify` command to run programs and have network requests automatically sent through the [Tor proxy network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29). For example:

```
torsocks firefox
```

Or, to do software upgrades...

```
sudo -i
torsocks apt-get update 
torsocks apt-get dist-upgrade
```

For a more "user-friendly" experience with Tor, download their [browser bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en). It comes in a compressed file which you can right-click in the file manager and extract. Navigate to the extracted directory and run `start-tor-browser.sh` with a double-click.

You can run Flash in the Tor browser: Enable it under Tools > Addons > Plugins.

Comment: Using tor, you certainly trade speed for privacy. Your internet will be s-l-o-w.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I installed tor but this part faild : "torsocks firefox" and software upgrades ...

I saw this message in Terminal :

11:20:50 libtorsocks(4644): WARNING: The symbol res_querydomain() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
  Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_querydomain() with the reported error: Not Found

Comment: Just ignore those warnings. You can check whether Tor is enabled at https://check.torproject.org/

Comment: Sometimes the programs started with `torsocks` refuses to start in Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 1):

There are some free VPN providers too, like [vpnbook](http://www.vpnbook.com/). These free services are usually donation based, so if you can, don't forget to donate so they can keep the service free.

Comment: I still have problem with my connection

I could not install tor browser completely ..

I could not open vpnbook ...

Comment: @user254862 [Here](http://www.vpnbook.com/howto/setup-openvpn-on-ubuntu) is how to set up vpnbook with openvpn. But it also works with pptp, I usually use it with pptp.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the add-ons list on firefox and search vpn. you can find plenty of free vpn extensions like Hoxx VPN and Hotsposhield

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. **Create an account** on hub.docker.com (https://hub.docker.com/signup) and **login**
2. Go to https://labs.play-with-docker.com/ (and log in with **same
   credentials** if required)
3. Click on the **Start** button (visible after signup and login)
4. A "**Lab Window"** will be opened
5. Click on **Add new instance**  and a "**Console window**" will be opened
6. **Copy and paste** the following in the terminal/console:

> docker run --name chrome --privileged -p 3000:3000 -d tekfik/chrome

8. After that, a **balloon/button/breadcrumb** will be added on the page
   **near the "OPEN PORT"** button
9. **Click that button** and you will be navigated to **a new tab** that will have a chrome browser opened in it.

**NOTE: The session will be limited to 4 hrs, use this for educational purposes only.**