# How can I use youtube-dl using tor browser settings in terminal

Tags: tor, youtube-dl

How can I use youtube-dl using tor browser settings in terminal.Can I use terminal to use tor settings.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429607/how-can-i-access-blocked-sites-for-free/429620#429620

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `tor` installed, you can use `torify`:

```
torify youtube-dl ...
```

Comment: great! For mac solution brew install tor torsocks & tor & torify youtube-dl ...